# how do i fix error laravel Route not defined

Tags: laravel

I'm getting route not defined error, I hope you can give some help.

```
<form action="{{ route('post.store') }}" 
    method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

---

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware'=>'auth'], function () {

    // route for post
    Route::get('/post/create', 'PostsController@create');
    Route::post('/post/store', 'PostsController@store');

    // route for categories
    Route::get('/category/create', 'CategorysController@create');
    Route::get('/category/store', 'CategorysController@store');

});
```

Answer (score 2):

**OPTION 1 (for all type controller)**

```
Route::get('post/store', 'PostsController@store')->name('your_route_name');
```

You can call this route like this: `{{ route('your_route_name') }}`

**OPTION 2 ( if your controller is a resource controller)**

```
Route::resource('post', 'PostsController');
```

You can call this route like this:

```
{{ route('post.store') }}
{{ route('post.edit', $post->id) }}
{{ route('post.create') }}
{{ route('post.uodate', $post->id) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use named route but you have not named it yet. So add this:

```
Route::post('/post/store', 'PostsController@store')->name('post.store');
```

Answer (score 0):

change your route:

```
<form action="{{ route('post.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

to:

```
<form action="{{ url('/post/store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: The other answers are better approaches, as they'll work OK if the Laravel app isn't at the domain's root (like `example.com/app`).